# awk - round to 2 decimals

Tags: command-line, awk

I am computing the percentages of every item in a column of a file using the following awk command:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$2;x+=(b[NR]=$2);c[NR]=$1}END{while(++i<=NR)print c[i]"\t"a[i]"\t"100*b[i]/x"%"}' file.txt > out_file.txt
```

file.txt

```
N    38668442   
V    14008521   
ADJ  16112215
```

out_file.txt

```
N    38668442   56,213%
V    14008521   20,3644%
ADJ  16112215   23,4226%
```

However, I would like the percentages in the out_file.txt to be rounded to 2 decimals.

desired out_file.txt

```
N    38668442   56,21%
V    14008521   20,37%
ADJ  16112215   23,42%
```

Referring to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696096/awk-calculate-sum-of-2nd-column-and-percentage-wrt-sum-and-print

I tried to integrate `printf "%s,%d,%0.2f%\n` into my code which raises an argument error even by decreasing the arguments and limit the expression to `%0.2f%\n`.

```
 awk '{a[NR]=$2;x+=(b[NR]=$2);c[NR]=$1}END{while(++i<=NR)printf "%s,%d,%0.2f%\n",c[i]"\t"a[i]"\t"100*b[i]/x"%"}' file.txt > out_file.txt
```

Also `bc` did not work out. Why does it not produce the desired output? In my opinion, it should work as I found the expression `printf "%0.2f\n"` in several posts concerning the same issue. Do I miss something trivial?

I greatly appreciate any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the syntax of the `printf` command (which closely follows that of the underlying `C` function: see for example [`man 3 printf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/printf.3.html) for full documentation).

`printf` takes a *format string* consisting of a sequence of *format specifiers* and other literal characters, followed by as many comma-separated arguments as necessary to fill the given format. In your command

```
printf "%s,%d,%0.2f%\n",c[i]"\t"a[i]"\t"100*b[i]/x"%"
```

you are telling it to expect 3 values (a `%s`, a `%d`, and a `%0.2f`) but are giving it a single, concatenated, string argument `c[i]"\t"a[i]"\t"100*b[i]/x"%"`. Hence it will run out of arguments during the assignment.

What you presumably intended is

```
printf "%s\t%d\t%0.2f%%\n", c[i], a[i], 100*b[i]/x
```

(the tabs go inside the format string; the `%%` corresponds to a literal `%` i.e. prevents `%` from being interpreted as the start of another format specifier).

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation and your help! It all makes sense now and I understand it finally! Also, the solution is great and works perfectly as always! I really appreciate your effort! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a function like this which fixes the annoying fact that awk rounds 0.5, etc. down.

```
function round(number, nDecimals,
    
    coef, i)
{
    coef = 1
    
    for (i = 1; i <= nDecimals; ++i)
    {
        coef *= 10
    }
    
    number *= coef
    
    number >= 0 ? number += 0.5 : number -= 0.5
    
    number = int(number)
    number /= coef
    
    return number
}
```

Then you can write this to print the input rounded to two decimals:

```
print round($0, 2)
```